# O(1) solution for number of times to apply iterated function

Tags: inequality, function-and-relation-composition

Is there an O(1) solution for finding the number of times to apply an simple iterated function to satisfy an inequality?

For example, if the function is

$$f(n) = 0.5n - 10; n > 100$$
and we want to solve
$$\min (i \ge 0: f^i(n)\le 100)$$

Is there an $O(1)$ solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps you mean max rather than min?

Comment: $O(1)$ (uniform in the right side of the inequality) is certainly unachievable, because the answer (if large) will require more than $O(1)$ time just to write down, never mind to compute.

Comment: In reply to your first comment, I've edited the example to be strictly decreasing.

Comment: I mean the minimum number of times to apply the function so that it is less than 100. So, the minimum i. Is that what the latter means?

Comment: I should probably clarify that I meant to have $n$ as an initial value, then find the amount of times to apply $f$ to the result of the previous $f$. I am looking for the number of times $f$ is applied to get the result less than 100

Comment: @mvw: I took it to mean that he knows a particular $n$ and wants to know when the iteration started at _that_ $n$ will cross the threshold.

Comment: @NickDeFilippis The answer is yes, there is for your linear iteration functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a good *general* theory that you can throw any function at and get good results.

In this case, however, the trick is to change the variable such that the function becomes a simple multiplication. We can do that by setting $m=n+a$, so our original iteration
$$ n \mapsto 1.2 n - 10 $$
becomes
$$ m \mapsto 1.2 (m-a) - 10 + a $$
which rearranges to
$$ m \mapsto 1.2m + (a - 10 - 1.2a) $$
Here we want to constant term to be 0; solving $a-10-1.2a=0$ yields $a=-50$, so with $m=n-50$ we have
$$ m \mapsto 1.2 m $$

Then $n = 100 $ corresponds to $m = 50 $, so the $i$ for which $1.2^i m = 50$ must be $\log_{1.2}(50/m)$.

However, it does not really make sense to ask for the *first* $i$ for which $f^i(n)\le 100$, because the iteration causes the point to diverge *away from* $n=50$ -- so unless the initial $n$ is *already* less than $100$, no amount of iterating the function will ever make it become less than $100$.

Comment: I've edited the example to be strictly decreasing, and for n > 100

Answer (score 0):

**Task:**

Given $n > 100$ we have the set
$$
A_n = \{ i\in \mathbb{N} \mid f^i(n) \le 100 \}
$$
Wanted is the minimum of $A_n$. We write
$$
F(n) = \min A_n
$$
and assign it the value $\bot$ if the minimum does not exist.

**Calculating $f^i$ from $f$:**

If we have
$$
f(n) = c\, n - d \quad (c, d \ge 0)
$$
then
$$
f^2(n) 
= c(c \, n - d) -d 
= c^2 \, n - d (c + 1) 
= c' \, n - d' \quad (c', d' \ge 0)
$$
and thus
$$
f^i(n) = c^{(i)} n - d^{(i)} \quad (c^{(i)}, d^{(i)} \ge 0)
$$
with
$$
c^{(i)} = c^i \\
d^{(1)} = d \\
d^{(2)} = c d + d = (c+1) d \\
d^{(3)} = c((c+1) d) + d = (c(c+1) + 1) d = (c^2 + c + 1) d \\
d^{(i+1)} = c \, d^{(i)} + d \quad (i \ge 1) \\
d^{(i+1)} = d \sum_{k=0}^i c^i = 
\begin{cases}
d (c^{i+1}-c)/(c-1) & \text{for } c \ne 1, i \ge 1 \\
d \, (i + 1) & \text{for } c = 1, i \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
which leads to
$$
f^i(n) = 
\begin{cases}
c \, n - d                 & \text{for } c \ne 1, i = 1 \\
c^i \, n - d (c^i-c)/(c-1) & \text{for } c \ne 1, i \ge 2 \\
n - d \, i                 & \text{for } c = 1
\end{cases}
$$

**Solution:**

With the help of the above it just needs a couple of case distinctions depending on $n, c, d$ to either come up with a suitable $i$ or determining that no such $i$ exists. This is a $O(1)$ algorithm.

Here are some examples:

For $c = 1$ this means
$$
f^i(n) = n - d\, i \le 100 \Rightarrow \\
n - 100 \le d \, i \Rightarrow \\
F(n) =
\begin{cases}
\bot & \text{for } d = 0 \\
\lceil (n - 100)/d \rceil & \text{for } d \ne 0
\end{cases}
$$
For $c \ne 1$ and $i\ge 2$ we have
$$
c^i \, n - d (c^i-c)/(c-1) \le 100 \Rightarrow \\
(n - d/(c-1)) c^i \le 100 - dc/(c-1) 
$$
This requires a case distinction for $n - d/(c-1)$. If it is negative, thus $n < d/(c-1)$ and $c >1$ we have
$$
i \ge \frac{\ln\left(\frac{100-dc/(c-1)}{n - d/(c-1)}\right)}{\ln(c)} \\
F(n) = \left\lceil \frac{\ln\left(\frac{100-dc/(c-1)}{n - d/(c-1)}\right)}{\ln(c)} \right\rceil
$$
The other cases are handled in a similar way.